# How do I add a custom view to a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, drawing, scrollview

So, I followed a tutorial for drawing stuff on android. I have created a Panel class that extends SurfaceView that I draw on using a thread. Now I want to put this Panel in a scroll view, specifically one that scrolls horizontally so that I can draw stuff wider than the screen. I would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in the XML of the project what you want to do is, whatever you want to be int the scrollview, you put inside a scrollview in xml.
it would be in between:

`<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">`

and:
`</ScrollView>`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your custom component is named (the class) MyCustomComponent and the package it's in is org.neteinstein.code

The xml would be:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

            <org.neteinstein.code.MyCustomComponent android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 

</HorizontalScrollView >
```